# Cannot dynamically load vue component in build mode

Tags: javascript, android, vue.js

I have framework7 VueJs application running on Xamarin Android webview. In one page I am dynamically load vue pages to a popup. It is loading correctly in dev mode (loading from network). But not in build mode. But if I manfully import these files, it also works in build mode. So that mean the path also correct.

```
<div class="card-content padding-horizontal padding-top">
    <div class="terms-block scrolling">
        <div ref="content">
             <component :is="dynamicComponent" /> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'
import { markRaw } from 'vue';


data() {
return {
    dynamicComponent: null
       }
}

loadStatement: function () {

    let filePath;

     if (app.device.android) {
         filePath = `../pages/component/PrivacyPolicy/v1/android/PrivacyPolicy-${this.languageTypeCode}.vue`;
     } else if (app.device.ios) {
         filePath = `../pages/component/PrivacyPolicy/v1/ios/PrivacyPolicy-${this.languageTypeCode}.vue`;
     }

    import(/* @vite-ignore */filePath)
        .then((module) => {
            this.dynamicComponent = markRaw(module.default);
        })
        .catch((ex) => {
            if (app.device.android) {
                this.dynamicComponent = markRaw(defineAsyncComponent(() => import(/* @vite-ignore */`../pages/component/PrivacyPolicy/v1/android/PrivacyPolicy-en.vue`)))
            } else if (app.device.ios) {
                this.dynamicComponent = markRaw(defineAsyncComponent(() => import(/* @vite-ignore */`../pages/component/PrivacyPolicy/v1/ios/PrivacyPolicy-en.vue`)))
            }
            console.error("%O", ex)
            //f7.toast.create({ text: this.LocalizationResources('Privacy_Policy_Not_Available', 'Privacy policy not available for the selected language at the moment', 20, 19), closeTimeout: 4000 }).open();
        });
}
```

I am getting this exception in the console

```
Error: file:///android_asset/views/www/pages/component/PrivacyPolicy/v1/android/PrivacyPolicy-en.vue,  (SystemJS https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/main/docs/errors.md#3)
    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/views/www/assets/polyfills-legacy.js:1:39793)
message
: 
"file:///android_asset/views/www/pages/component/PrivacyPolicy/v1/android/PrivacyPolicy-en.vue,  (SystemJS https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/main/docs/errors.md#3)"
stack
: 
"Error: file:///android_asset/views/www/pages/component/PrivacyPolicy/v1/android/PrivacyPolicy-en.vue,  (SystemJS https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/main/docs/errors.md#3)\n    at HTMLScriptElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/views/www/assets/polyfills-legacy.js:1:39793)"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
constructor
: 
ƒ Error()
message
: 
""
name
: 
"Error"
toString
: 
ƒ toString()
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the wrapper `defineAsyncComponent` to declare the module as a Vue component? `this.dynamicComponent = defineAsyncComponent(module.default);`